# Call to a member function getData() on null in /var/www/html/app/code/Macademy/Blog/Controller/Index/ListAction.php:21

Tags: dependency-injection, magento2

I was learning about using ObjectManager in Magento2. Can you please check why this is not working?

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Macademy\Blog\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface;

class ListAction implements HttpGetActionInterface
{
    private $session;

    public function __construct(
        Session $session,
    ) {
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($this->session->getData());
        die();
    }
}
```

This is "ListAction.php". The path of the file is app/code/Macademy/Blog/Controller/Index/ListAction.php

I found that it is not a best way to use ObjectManager directly. Anyone have inputs?

Answer (score 0):

Update for the question's answer from the author. I got the resolution after running the commands:

bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento cache:flush